# Sent messages are shown duplicated in my List View

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

```
    private class getItemLists extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    private Context mContext;

    public getItemLists(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ld.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        // Intent i = new Intent("notify.intent.MAIN");
        // mContext.sendBroadcast(i);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            Chatdb db = new Chatdb(mContext);
            String[] smsid = db.getAllinboxsmsid();

            // Create Inbox box URI
            Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

            // List required columns
            String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body",
                    "date", "read" };

            // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content
            // Provider
            ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();

            // Fetch Inbox SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
            Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, null, null, null);
            boolean exists = false;
            if (c.moveToLast()) {
                do {
                    exists = false;
                    publishProgress((c.getCount() - c.getPosition() + ";" + c
                            .getCount()));

                    for (int x = 0; x < smsid.length; x++) {
                        if (smsid[x].equals(c.getString(0))) {
                            exists = true;

                        }

                    }

                    if (!exists) {

                        if (c.getString(4).equals("0")) {

                            smsRead = "1";
                        } else {
                            smsRead = "0";

                        }
                        db.addMsgWithTime(c.getString(1), c.getString(2),
                                "1", "0", "L", c.getString(0),
                                c.getString(3), smsRead);
                        publishProgress((c.getCount() - c.getPosition()
                                + ";" + c.getCount()));

                        // Intent in = new
                        // Intent("SmsMessage.intent.MAIN").putExtra(
                        // "get_msg", c.getString(1));
                        //
                        // // You can place your check conditions here(on
                        // the SMS or the
                        // // sender)
                        // // and then send another broadcast
                        // SuperMain.this.sendBroadcast(in);

                    }
                } while (c.moveToPrevious());
            }

            // c.close();
            //
            String[] SentSmsId = db.getAllsentsmsid();

            Uri sentURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");

            // List required columns
            String[] reqColsSent = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body",
                    "date", "read" };

            // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content
            // Provider

            // Fetch Inbox SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
            c = cr.query(sentURI, reqColsSent, null, null, null);

            if (c.moveToLast()) {
                do {

                    exists = false;
                    publishProgress((c.getCount() - c.getPosition() + ";" + c
                            .getCount()));
                    for (int x = 0; x < SentSmsId.length; x++) {
                        if (SentSmsId[x].equals(c.getString(0))) {
                            exists = true;

                        }

                    }
                    if (!exists) {

                        db.addMsgWithTime(c.getString(1), c.getString(2),
                                "0", "0", "S", c.getString(0),
                                c.getString(3), "1");
                        // db.close();

                        publishProgress((c.getCount() - c.getPosition()
                                + ";" + c.getCount()));

                    }
                } while (c.moveToPrevious());

            }

            c.close();
            db.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
        }

        return "done";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String done) {
        super.onPostExecute(done);

        // Toast.makeText(mContext, "Messages have synced successfully",
        // 3).show();
        ld.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }

}
```

This is my Loading procedure of Inbox and Sent messages and showing at mu list view.
here ld is my loader... showing when data is loading

```
    public String[] getAllsentsmsid() {

    String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_SMSID + " FROM " + TABLE_THREAD
            + " WHERE " + KEY_SMSID + "<>'0' AND " + KEY_ORIGIN + "='0'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    String[] allid = new String[cursor.getCount()];

    int x = 0;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            allid[x] = cursor.getString(0);
            x++;

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    db.close();
    return allid;

}

public String[] getAllinboxsmsid() {

    String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_SMSID + " FROM " + TABLE_THREAD
            + " WHERE " + KEY_SMSID + "<>'0' AND " + KEY_ORIGIN + "='1'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    String[] allid = new String[cursor.getCount()];

    int x = 0;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            allid[x] = cursor.getString(0);
            x++;

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    db.close();
    return allid;

}
```

These are my database methods where I am storing messages id and save them in my database.

In my list view making duplicate threads of chatting.

Comment: Are you using custom ListView ? You have any if-else blocks in your getView() method

Comment: Yes I am using custom ListView, I have used if-else conditions.
if(view==null){

view.setTag(viewholder);
   

  } else {
   viewholder = (ViewHolderItem) view.getTag();
  }
}

Comment: While fetching..you could have used DISTINCT query..Also is KEY_SMSID the primary key?

Comment: Yes KEY_SMSID is my primary key.. but I haven't used DISTINCT query while fetching @AndroidMech

Comment: Tried DISTINCT but it is not working for me :( @AndroidMech